# How to check if row exists or not before insertion?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I want to insert records to my sqllite database but before insertion i have to check if the record exists .

I used this code but still say no such column and stopped working although the record exists .

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_TEAM + " WHERE "
            + TEAM_TABLE_NAME + " = " + name+";";

    Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (c != null) {
         return true;
    }
    return false;
```

Comment: If the column `TEAM_TABLE_NAME` is a unique or primary key, just use `INSERT OR IGNORE`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the recommended way to use `rawQuery()`:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_TEAM + " WHERE " + TEAM_TABLE_NAME + " = ?";
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[] {name});
```

so you pass `name` as a parameter to the query and avoid the risk of [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).
In your code you only check if the `Cursor` object is `null` and not if it contains any rows which is the right thing to do.
So return the result of `getCount() > 0` like this:

```
return c.getCount() > 0;
```

This will return `true` if **the name already exists in the table**.
As for the `no such column` error, this is something different. 
First make sure that `TEAM_TABLE_NAME` is the correct name of the column and if it is then maybe you made changes to the names of the columns tha are not reflected to the database. 
So uninstall the app from the device so the database is deleted and then rerun to recreate the database with the new names of the columns.